# JavaScript: A button that is equivalent to rotating the device to landscape view

Tags: javascript, webview

I'm trying to create a button that allows me to set the mobile screen orientation from portrait to landscape when the button is clicked.
How can I do that, without actually rotate the device?

Comment: Try this: `screen.orientation.lock('landscape');` ( https://www.w3.org/TR/screen-orientation/#examples )

Comment: I got error message like this : Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: screen.orientation.lock() is not available on this device. Is it because of using the chrome mobile simulator ? `onclick="screen.orientation.lock('landscape')"` this is all I did to my button

Comment: no - it is not support yet by your browser - so you need to find some alternative approach

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Screen.orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation) API for this purpose. 
An important point to note is, before using `screen.orientation.lock('landscape')` you first need to enable **fullscreen mode** on your device with `document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()`.

Regarding `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: screen.orientation.lock() is not available on this device.`  This is not supported by your browser. Try running on your phone's browser it should work. It worked for me.

**Please look into this [example](https://www.w3.org/TR/screen-orientation/#examples) it perfectly matches your need.** With this you can change orientation from portrait to landscape and back without actually rotating your phone.